# Enable Github Copilot "dialog" to accept or deny suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

At the beginning of my use of GitHub copilot this "dialog" used to show above the line I was typing.

But after update the extension on VSCode to the version 1.86.82 that stoped showing.

Is there a way to enable it again?

[image]